# onSaveInstanceState and finish()

Tags: android, android-activity

**Short question:** Is it possible to save data using `onSaveInstanceState()` method, then call `finish()` on Activity and upon next start of the Activity to get the data back in `savedInstanceState`? Or does `finish()` of an Activity mean the data are gone?

If first answer is correct, I have some problem in my implementation because I am getting `null` in `onCreate()` although the data was saved. If second answer is correct, I will have to re-think how I connect my Activities together :o)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to save data using onSaveInstanceState() method, then call finish() on Activity and upon next start of the Activity to get the data back in savedInstanceState?

No.

> Or does finish() of an Activity mean the data are gone?

Yes. The saved instance state `Bundle` is for cases where, from the user's perspective, your activity is still around, but it is being destroyed for technical reasons:

- Configuration changes (e.g., screen rotation)
- Process termination (with the user returning to your app fairly quickly)

If `finish()` is called for other reasons — you calling it directly, user presses BACK, etc. — then the saved instance state is no longer needed and can be discarded.

As a result, the saved instance state `Bundle` is for transient data that you would like to retain but are comfortable with losing in the face of configuration changes and process termination, such as the contents of a partially-filled-in form.

Comment: Please note that if you wonder only for screen rotation without any dialogs just edit text fields - you don't need to implement onSaveInstanceState - there is only one must be - all your edit text have to have ID value in xml.

Comment: now my problem to solve is: I have main activity and three other activities, that shall be invoked by clicking on buttons in main. When I go to activities, there can be an action performed and I need to be able to inform the main activity about the result. I know how to use Intent to start an activity and to pass some data upon starting the app. But when I keep starting new activities, the old ones remain and making mess. This is why used finish() to terminate them. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: @Ellrohir: "I need to be able to inform the main activity about the result" -- have the main activity call `startActivityForResult()` to start up the other activities. Have those activities call `setResult()` and `finish()` when the user does something to indicate what the result should be. However, those other activities are then destroyed.